# Subclassing in python and __init__ : practical example

Tags: python, class, inheritance

In python I can do this:

```
import mechanize
class MC (object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.Browser = mechanize.Browser()          
          self.Browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
      def open (self,url):
          self.url = url
          self.Browser.open(self.url)
```

My question is: how can I `__init__` a parent class method in a subclass (that is something like this):

```
class MC (mechanize.Browser):
      def __init__(self):
          self.Browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
```

Help much appriciated!

Comment: One of the key concepts of object inheritance is that the child inherits all of the properties (attributes, methods) of the parent. Maybe you should look into an introduction to OOP, again :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the method directly, methods on base classes are available on your instance during initialisation:

```
class MC(mechanize.Browser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.set_handle_equiv(True)
```

You probably want to call the base-class `__init__` method as well though:

```
class MC(mechanize.Browser):
    def __init__(self):
        mechanize.Browser.__init__(self)
        self.set_handle_equiv(True)
```

We need to call the `__init__` directly because `Browser` is an [old-style python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python); in a new-style python class we'd use `super(MC, self).__init__()` instead, where the [`super()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) provides a proxy object that searches the base class hierarchy to find the next matching method you want to call.

Comment: I don't know mechanize, but it seems likely that you might need to call `mechanize.Browser.__init__(self)` first to make sure the Browser is initialized properly.

Comment: @Pieters: I actually tried this. What mgilson is suggesting solves the problem :)